# How can I get active range/selection in Google Spreadsheets when a script is deployed as a Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I found that functions like getActiveRange(), getActiveSelection() work only when a script runs as a Custom Function in Spreadsheets or a Container Extension (see [Execution Methods for Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_methods)). Is my observation correct? Is there any way to deploy script as a Web App, open a spreadsheet using [SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp#openById) and get active range/selection, assuming the owner of the spreadsheet has it opened in Drive?

The matter is I'm making an extension for Google Spreadsheets, but for building my custom UI I don't want to use [Html Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) or [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp), I want traditional plain HTML/JS. So, I render my UI on a page, I open a spreadsheet in iframe and then my UI calls Google Scripts as a service, meaning I deploy scripts as Web Apps (which automate different spreadsheet tasks) and call them with URL parameters. It works fine except I can't get active range/selection which is a deal breaker for my application.

Answer (score 3):

Well I'm afraid you can't since your observation is correct.

But there is a possible workaround if you use a second sheet in your main spreadsheet and an `onEdit()` trigger that monitors the active cell in the main sheet.
Then an external webApp could poll the value on this second sheet quite simply.

Here is the (simple) code in the spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
 // if(sh.getName()!='main sheet'){return};
  ss.toast('hi = '+r.getA1Notation()+'/'+sh.getName()+'   value='+r.getValue());
  var tracker = ss.getSheetByName('tracker sheet');
  tracker.getRange(tracker.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(r.getA1Notation());
  Browser.msgBox('new')
}
```

And a simple webApp that shows the result like this :

```
function doGet(){
  var targetId = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dFRqUFVMSjdiSU9EV1pGcG1hQ3FlT1E'
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId).getSheetByName('tracker sheet');
  var cell = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1).getValue();
  var html ="<!DOCTYPE html><body>Active Cell in your sheet is "+cell+"</body></html>";
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('onEdit result')
}
```

A [test sheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dFRqUFVMSjdiSU9EV1pGcG1hQ3FlT1E) (with a "main sheet" on which you can write and a "tracker sheet" that holds the A1 notation) and the webapp attached to it [is here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxpUjmetuivrRmgbhsFscXwthnnsomR8RS5YaE0U36j1fAlBzt5/exec)

I added a "toast" to monitor the onEdit function for test purpose only

Comment: Thanks Serge! Unfortunately onEdit doesn't work for me, I need something like onSelectionChanged... Is it possible to trigger a Custom Function in a test sheet from my webApp?

Comment: Not that I know in GAS (because of execution methods you mentioned). Maybe someone else will suggest something but this is beyond my knowledge... sorry

Comment: @xman85 do you mean to do something within a spreadsheet (like change a value of a cell) after some component of your webapp has changed (for example a listbox)? You could add to the component (lstbx) a serverclickhandler with a changehandler and than use the same function off the spreadsheet in your web app script. (This would be with copy paste & SpreadsheetApp.openById())

Comment: updated to use html service and keep a list of all the onEdit cell positions, just for fun ;)