# getA1Notation script always return A1 as the active cell or selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**------------------------Update 05/04/18----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
Context :
I'm developping an extension for Google Spreadsheets, but for building my custom UI I don't use Html Service or UI Service. I use traditional plain HTML/JS. So, I render my UI on the sidebar.
**------------------------End Update 05/04/18---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

This is how I select the active range from the spreadsheet in a script :

```
function GetSelectionSpreadSheet()
{
  var app = SpreadsheetApp ;
  var classeur = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var feuille = classeur.getActiveSheet();
  var selectedRng = feuille.getActiveRange();
  var val = selectedRng.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log(val);
  return val;  
}
```

And this how I call this script :

```
  window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    window.gapi.client.load('script', 'v1', () => {
      const client_id = 'xxx';
      const scope = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui',
        /** View and manage your spreadsheets in Google Drive */
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
      ];
      const immediate = false;
      window.gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id, scope, immediate }, (authResult) => {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          /** handle succesfull authorization */
          this.run();
        } else {
          /** handle authorization error */
        }
      });
    });
  });
});


 async run() {
    await window.gapi.client.script.scripts.run({
      scriptId: '1u59k_RlcvGfRGVheuS7xIWOHY-YDs8IKdY3VK6KQd_Nx7NuBlyqAnNEN',
      resource: {
        function: 'GetSelectionSpreadSheet',
        devMode: true
      }
    }).then((resp) => {
      const result = resp.result;
      if (result.error && result.error.status) {
        console.log('Error calling API:' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
      } else if (result.error) {
        const error = result.error.details[0];
        console.log('Script error message: ' + error.errorMessage);

        if (error.scriptStackTraceElements) {
          console.log('Script error stacktrace:');
        }
      } else {
        const folderSet = result.response.result;
        console.log(folderSet);
      }
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Because when called remotely, there is no associated session. Thus, the default cell - A1 - is returned.

Comment: But why some functions likes getValues(), getSheetName() are working well when called remotely ?

Comment: propagation of defaults. A bound script -> `getActiveSpreadsheet` knows which one to use. `getActiveSheet`, remotely, returns the first one. `getSheetByName` requires a name, not session information. `getValues` is applied to whatever range is being used.

Comment: thanks for yours answers, but what can I do to have the functions getA1Notation and getActiveSheet working remotely ?

Comment: `getActiveSheet` and `getActiveRange` cannot work when there is no user that is currently using the spreadsheet from Google Sheets. If you want to select a range, you must use a different method to define both the desired sheet, and the desired range.

Comment: Ok, on my case I display an UI on the side bar to select some data. I have a input item where I want to display the range selected. So there is a user currently using the spreadsheet from Google Sheets but getActiveSheet and getActiveRange call remotely don't return the good data.

Comment: Use Google's built in async communication method for bound UI applications. i.e. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(htmlFunction).GetSelectionSpreadSheet()` where your client-side success handler function then uses the return value from the called server function. If you want to handle uncaught server-side errors in the client code, you'll need a client-side failure handler.

Comment: Thank you a lot @tehhowch for yours rapids answer. But I don't precised it  (I'm sorry) but my UI is not defined on the Apps Script editor but it's an external application which is display on the side bar. So the google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(htmlFunction).GetSelectionSpreadSheet() isn't available !

Comment: How are you displaying your sidebar in Google Sheets? If you are using the native sidebar (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) then you have those methods. If not, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143854/how-can-i-get-active-range-selection-in-google-spreadsheets-when-a-script-is-dep Either way, you have not provided a very useful problem description in your initial question, and **must** improve it by adding this context.

Comment: What do you mean by "extension for Google Spreadsheets"? Is it a Google Sheets add-on or a web browser extension?

Comment: I mean a Google Sheets add-on.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because there is no active selection when the Spreadsheet is just linked rather than being opened.

Comment: Ok but when I call the function getA1Notation remotely my spreadsheet is opened.

Comment: Is there any solution that you've found for this, Sami?

Comment: @CoderSaru the solution that I have found is to use the spreadsheet ID and the sheet name instead of getActiveSpreadsheet() and getActiveSheet().