# is there a way to make getActiveRange() function work on a different spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i need a code to take the active selection from spreadsheet A and place it in spreadsheet B transposed, but when i try to get the active range from sheet A it always returns A1 which is not true, here is the code:

```
function newVariant(cell) {
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("sheetID").getActiveSheet();
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  console.log(srcRange);
}
```

this is what come on the log:
[image]

i read that "getActiveRange()" only work with the current Spreadsheet only so i tried to add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly" so that i'll have access to all my google sheets but i still get "A1" as the selected range while it's not.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods), you need a bound script to use methods like [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverange), because they refer to the spreadsheet linked (bounded) to the script.

If you have a script bound to spreadsheet A, you can't use it to access the active range on spreadsheet B, because it's bound only to spreadsheet A.

> i read that "getActiveRange()" only work with the current Spreadsheet
> only so i tried to add
> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly" so that i'll
> have access to all my google sheets but i still get "A1" as the
> selected range while it's not.

The concept of bound doesn't really depend on the permissions you give to the script, so changing that won't make any difference. Also, you get "A1" because that's the default value returned by [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverange).

A [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145152/3751868) would be to use an [edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to keep track of the active range on spreadsheet B, then you can get that range using the script bound to spreadsheet A.

Comment: does highlighting some cells trigger the onEdit()?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: then what should i do from client side to copy some data from spreadsheet A to spreadSheet B?

Comment: Attach the script to spreadsheet A (the one with the active range) ?